# Drive API not running?

Tags: java, android, list, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to list of all files within Google Drive using Drive API. I've found one API which gives me this list.

When I try to run this API in API explorer it works fine. Give me list of all files
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files

But when I copy paste url in browser & runs it proving API key, Show me an error.

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
{
 "error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
"message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
}
}
```

I'm pretty new in android. I just want retrieve file list. not search function.

Comment: May be those files doesn't have permissions or your key is wrong.

Comment: @RakeshChouhan How to resolve this. I'm trying from 2 days. I've created new key but same error.

Comment: You need to login using the OAuth process which includes authorization and scopes. API key is not enough. I've done this in Javascript but since you're on Android, try the Drive [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android).

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be your file permission check this documentation for the file permissions -

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions

Answer (score 0):

Only OAuth 2.0 is supported for Google Drive API.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth